# Inverse normal mixture cdf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the inverse cdf for a normal mixture. I have written the following code:

```
clear vq
vd = randn(1000,1);%create uniform random samples that will 
%spread over the whole range of the forecast variable
X=(-5:0.0001:5)'; %set values to calculate CDF for to create a lookup table
k = 5; %number of mixture components
GMModel = fitgmdist(X,k); %Fit Normal mixture distribution to data
normalcdf=cdf(GMModel,X); %Calculate the normal distribution fuction CDF
LookupNormCDF=[X, normalcdf]; %Create a lookup table for quartiles of the CDF

for i=1:length(vd)
vq(i) = (interp1(normalcdf,X,vd(i))); %Use the lookup table to 
%find each quartiles from the cdf value (vd)

end %loop through this for each value of vd
vq=vq';

figure;
plot(X,pdf(GMModel,X))
hold on
plot(X,cdf(GMModel,X))
```

As a test of my code above I have set k = 1 and compared with:

```
vq000=invnormcdf(vd);
```

Both scripts obviously give NaNs when vd is not in the range 0 to 1 however the results I get for vq are also NaN when vd is close to zero or one whereas I get a values in this case for vq000. Also there seems to be no correlation between the results (for k = 1) I get for vq and vq000 despite the same values for vd (same run of the script). I would have expected vq and vq000 to be more similar (e.g +/-0.2, obviously they cannot be exactly the same as I am using two different estimation methods).

The script I am using for invnormcdf is:

```
function x = invnormcdf(p)
%INVNORMCDF(P)  Normal quantile function
% X = INVNORMCDF(P) returns the P-th quantile of the standard normal distribution.
% In other words, it returns X such that P = NORMCDF(X).

x = erfinv(2*p-1)*sqrt(2);
```

Comment: So how is invnormcdf(vd) defined for you?

Comment: I have include the script I am using for invnormcdf above.

Comment: you need to explain a bit of your code dear?